# Non-linear classification with tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tflearn

I am new to machine learning and Tensorflow and want to do a simple 2-dimensional classification with data, that cannot be linear separated.

[image: Current Result]
On the left side, you can see the training data for the model.
The right side shows, what the trained model predicts.

As of now I am overfitting my model, so every possible input is fed to the model.
My expected result would be a very high accurancy as the model already 'knows' each answer.
Unfortunately the Deep Neural Network I am using is only able to separate by a linear divider, which doesn't fit my data.

This is how I train my Model:

```
def testDNN(data):
  """ 
  * data is a list of tuples (x, y, b), 
  * where (x, y) is the input vector and b is the expected output
  """
  # Build neural network
  net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 2])

  net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 100)
  net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 100)
  net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 100)


  net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
  net = tflearn.regression(net)

  # Define model
  model = tflearn.DNN(net)

  # check if we already have a trained model
  # Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
  model.fit(
    [(x,y) for (x,y,b) in data], 
    [([1, 0] if b else [0, 1]) for (x,y,b) in data], 
    n_epoch=2, show_metric=True)

  return lambda x,y: model.predict([[x, y]])[0][0]
```

Most of it is taken from the examples of tflearn, so I do not exactly understand, what every line does.

Comment: Try increase n_epoch?

Comment: Increasing n_epoch does not change the accurancy, which is around 50 %. like a coin flip would be.

Comment: not sure if this is a particular model choice that you do not want non-linearity following your initial three linear layers or something that tf-learn puts by default ( i dont know much about tf-learn) but having non-linearity there should help.

Answer (score 1):

You need an activation function in your network for non-linearity. An activation function is the way for a neural network to fit non-linear function. Tflearn by default uses a linear activation, you could change this to 'sigmoid' and see if the results improve.